# Designing a Java library with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am extracting some functionality from an existing program into a separate library.
This program uses Spring for dependency injection and other tasks and I'd like to keep using it in the library as well.

This library needs to monitor the filesystem for changes, so it will kick off some kind of separate thread to do this.

I don't really know what my options are for initialisation of the library:

- How do I initialise the library's context? I cannot assume that library users will make use of Spring too, but I can distribute Spring with the library.
- How do I manage my filesystem monitoring thread? Is it good design to expect the program to instantiate a main class of the library and the call init or something like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I initialise the library's context? I cannot assume that library users will make use of Spring too, but I can distribute Spring with the library.

It's up to your library to instantiate spring the way you need it. This is typically done in your interface entrypoint which delegates to a routine using e.g., `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to configure spring. A sample could be

```
public class SpringContextLoader {
   private static ApplicationContext ctx = null;
   public static void init() {
       if (ctx == null) {
          ctx = ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/applicatonContext.xml");
       }
   }
}
```

> How do I manage my filesystem monitoring thread? Is it good design to expect the program to instantiate a main class of the library and the call init or something like that?

In this case you will probably provide a non-daemon thread, e.g., a thread which must be terminated manually for the application to exit cleanly. Hence you should provide `start` and `stop` mechanisms. In your case these probably better be called `registerEventListener` and `unregisterAllEventListener` (since I'm guessing you want to pass filesystem events to the client ... ). Another alternative could be to use [`quartz`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) scheduling with spring.

Comment: Actually I don't need to pass FS events to the client. Is only for the library to be aware of available files, as it needs to access different versions of some files that get changed at random times. 

So it is for internal consumption of the library and I have it currently designed as a daemon thread, but I don't know what's the best way of handling a deamon thread from Spring.

Comment: @Jimenez, Simplest approach isn't always the worst: `new Thread(new Runnable()).setDaemon(true)`, unless you're going for the nice [`@Scheduled`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled) approach.

Comment: I know, that's the way it is now :) , but I was just curious to see if there was another better option.

Comment: @Jimenez, Spring is an `IoC` container in core, it doesn't concern itself with threading models which are already provided by the java language.

Answer (score 11):

> How do I initialise the library's context? I cannot assume that
>   library users will make use of Spring too, but I can distribute Spring
>   with the library.

I am writing a library using Spring context as well and I did something like that, assuming your library is called **FooLib**, has two services called **FooService** and **BarService** and a class called SpringContext that configures your spring context through java config:

```
public final class FooLib {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private FooLib() {
    }

    public static FooService getFooService() {
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(FooService.class);
    }

    public static BarService getBarService() {
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(BarService.class);
    }

    private static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        if (applicationContext == null) {
            applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringContext.class);
        }
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Then a client can use `BarService` this way:

```
BarService barService = FooLib.getBarService();
```

> How do I manage my filesystem monitoring thread? Is it good design to
>   expect the program to instantiate a main class of the library and the
>   call init or something like that?

You can start your monitoring subsystem statically within Spring context, inside the SpringContext class, for example.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.yourgroupid.foolib")
public class SpringContext {

    @Bean
    public MonitoringSystem monitoringSystem() {
        MonitoringSystem monitoringSystem = new MonitoringSystem();
        monitoringSystem.start();
        return monitoringSystem;
    }

}
```

That should be enough because Spring creates its beans eagerly by default.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

> How do I initialise the library's context? I cannot assume that library users will make use of Spring too, but I can distribute Spring with the library.

You can use a [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to read configuration settings from a (possibly external) property file, which can be edited by the users. This way users aren't exposed to the details of Spring, not even to XML config files.

> How do I manage my filesystem monitoring thread? Is it good design to expect the program to instantiate a main class of the library and the call init or something like that?

I recommend using the Java concurrency framework, specifically a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to run monitoring task(s) at specified intervals. However, you may want to hide this implementation detail from the users of your library, by only exposing some init method to pass in the desired timer interval.

Comment: Regarding the first part, I think a java library should be configurable through java API and not property files.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to configure your library to start a thread automatically, you have to define a class as starting point. Using Maven you can create an executable jar:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html
In your main class, simple use:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:myspring-context.xml");      
    context.registerShutdownHook();
```

For threads, you can try either implementing the runnable interface, and initialize a bean which starts the threads using spring task executors. A more elegant solution that I can suggest is however creating your thread as a pojo and then using spring task scheduler, as follows:

```
<bean id="threadPojo" class="com.mydomain.ThreadPojo">
</bean>
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="mydomainTaskScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="threadPojo" method="process" fixed-delay="${delay-pool}"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduler id="mydomainTaskScheduler" pool-size="${my-pool-size}" />
```

I hope it will be helpful.