# How to import Java project into eclipse from jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

So I've been given client code which is structured like this. The client-context.xml is the spring bean config.

```
client
|
+-- config
|   |
|   +--client.properties
|   +--client-context.xml
|   +--keystore.jks
|   +--request.xml
|   
+-- lib
|   |
|   +--client.jar
|   +--app-model.jar
|   +--spring-aop.jar
|   +--spring-beans.jar
|   +--spring-context.jar
|   -- other dependencies-- 
+--run.bat
```

I've unzipped the client.jar because I need to modify it.

It is structured like this

```
client-1.0
|
+--package
|  |
|  +--client.class
|  +--client.java
|  +--clientImpl.class
|  +--clientImpl.java
|
+--META-INF
|  |
|  +--MANIFEST.MF
```

I've tried creating a project in eclipse with the following structure. I also included the other jars as dependencies

```
client
|
+--src
|  |
|  +--package
|  |  |
|  |  +--client.java
|  |  +--clientImpl.java
|  |  
|  +--main
|  |  |
|  |  +--resources
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  +--client-context.xml
|  |  |  +--client.properties
|  |  |  +--keystore.jks
|  |  |  +--request.xml
|  |  
|  +--META-INF
|  |  |  
|  |  +--MANIFEST.MF
```

I get an exception

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [package.Client] is defined
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:319)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:985)
>       at package.ClientImpl.main(ClientImpl.java:164)

Here is the relevant par of my context

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:client.properties" />
</bean>

<util:properties id="ePSProperties" location="classpath:client.properties" />

<bean id="epsClient" class="package.ClientImpl" />
```

and the relevant part of the code, the exception is being thrown at ctx.getBean

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath*:client-context.xml");
    Client epsClient = ctx.getBean(Client.class);
    epsClient.sendReceiveXmls();
    epsClient.sendReceiveJavaObjects();
    ctx.close();
}
```

UPDATE: I figured it out, I moved my context.xml to the root of src. I'm not sure what the best practice is though.

Edit: I' trying to use this project as a library in a dynamic web project(maven project). My client-1.0 project is installed in the local repo.
The following is my client code.

```java
public class ClientImpl implements Client {


private static final String WS_ADDRESSING_ACTION = "http://www.example.org";

@Value("#{ePVSProperties['saml.issuer']}")
private String samlIssuer;

@Value("#{ePVSProperties['saml.name.id']}")
private String samlNameId;

@Value("#{ePVSProperties['facility.keystore.location']}")
private String facilityKeystoreLocation;

@Value("#{ePVSProperties['facility.keystore.password']}")
private String facilityKeystorePassword;

@Value("#{ePVSProperties['facility.keystore.type']}")
private String facilityKeystoreType;

@Value("#{ePVSProperties['ssl.debugging']}")
private String sslDebugging;

@Value("#{ePVSProperties['ssl.allow.unsafe.renegotiation']}")
private String allowUnsafeRenegotiation;

@Value("#{ePVSProperties['epvs.endpoint']}")
private String epvsEndpoint;

@Autowired
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;

public EPVSClientImpl() throws ConfigurationException {
    DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
    if(ctx== null)
   {        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:client-context.xml");
   }
}



@PostConstruct
public void initKeyStore() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", facilityKeystoreLocation);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", facilityKeystorePassword);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", facilityKeystoreType);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", facilityKeystoreLocation);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", facilityKeystorePassword);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", facilityKeystoreType);
    System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", allowUnsafeRenegotiation);
    if (sslDebugging != null && !sslDebugging.trim().isEmpty()) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", sslDebugging);
    }
}

public EnquiryResponse sendReceiveObjects(EnquiryRequest request) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending Java Object Request...");
        EnquiryResponse response = (EnquiryResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(epvsEndpoint, request,
                getCallback());
        return response;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private WebServiceMessageCallback getCallback() throws URISyntaxException {
    return new ActionCallback(new URI(WS_ADDRESSING_ACTION), new Addressing10()) {
        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
            super.doWithMessage(message);
            try {
                addSamlToken(message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public MessageIdStrategy getMessageIdStrategy() {
            return new UuidMessageIdStrategy();
        }
    };
}

private void addSamlToken(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, MarshallingException, TransformerException,
        GeneralSecurityException, XMLSignatureException, MarshalException, ParserConfigurationException,
        TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, SAXException {
    Assertion samlTokenAssertion = createSamlAssertion();
    Document samlTokenDocument = convertXMLObjectToDocument(samlTokenAssertion);
    Element samlTokenRootElement = samlTokenDocument.getDocumentElement();
    createSamlTokenSoapHeader(message, samlTokenRootElement);
}

private Assertion createSamlAssertion() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    DateTime now = new DateTime();

    Issuer issuer = create(Issuer.class, Issuer.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
    issuer.setValue(samlIssuer);

    NameID nameID = create(NameID.class, NameID.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
    nameID.setFormat(NameID.EMAIL);
    nameID.setValue(samlNameId);

    Subject subject = create(Subject.class, Subject.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
    subject.setNameID(nameID);

    Assertion assertion = create(Assertion.class, Assertion.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
    assertion.setID(new SecureRandomIdentifierGenerator().generateIdentifier());
    assertion.setIssueInstant(now);
    assertion.setIssuer(issuer);
    assertion.setSubject(subject);

    return assertion;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T create(Class<T> cls, QName qname) {
    return (T) ((XMLObjectBuilder<?>) Configuration.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(qname)).buildObject(qname);
}

private void createSamlTokenSoapHeader(WebServiceMessage message, Element samlToken)
        throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {
    SaajSoapMessage axiomMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
    Source source = new DOMSource(samlToken);
    SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) axiomMessage).getSoapHeader();
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(source, soapHeader.getResult());
}

private Document convertXMLObjectToDocument(XMLObject object)
        throws IOException, MarshallingException, TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = null;
    documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    Marshaller marshaller = Configuration.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(object);
    marshaller.marshall(object, document);

    return document;
}
```

This is my context file

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="package" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file*:/src/epvs-client.properties" />
</bean>

<util:properties id="ePVSProperties" location="file*:/src/client.properties" />

<bean id="epvsClient" class="package.ClientImpl" />

<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender" />
    </property>
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="securityInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean class="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPaths">
        <list>
            <value>package.webservice.dom.external.v1</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="securityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securementActions" value="Signature Encrypt" />
    <property name="securementEncryptionCrypto" ref="keyStore" />
    <property name="securementEncryptionUser" value="${server.certificate.alias}" />
    <property name="securementEncryptionSymAlgorithm">
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants.TRIPLE_DES" />
    </property>
    <property name="securementSignatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference" />
    <property name="securementSignatureCrypto" ref="keyStore" />
    <property name="securementSignatureParts" value="{}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;{}{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion}Assertion" />
    <property name="securementUsername" value="${facility.key.pair.alias}" />
    <property name="securementPassword" value="${facility.private.key.password}" />
    <property name="validationActions" value="Encrypt Signature" />
    <property name="validationSignatureCrypto" ref="keyStore" />
    <property name="validationDecryptionCrypto" ref="keyStore" />
    <property name="validationCallbackHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.KeyStoreCallbackHandler">
            <property name="privateKeyPassword" value="${facility.private.key.password}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="keyStore" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
    <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="file:${facility.keystore.location}" />
    <property name="keyStorePassword" value="${facility.keystore.password}" />
    <property name="keyStoreType" value="${facility.keystore.type}" />
</bean>
```

I call this library by creating an instance of the client.

```java
ClientImpl clientImpl = new ClientImpl();
```

but I'm getting an Null pointer exception in when I call sendReceiveObject at

```java
EnquiryResponse response = (EnquiryResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(epvsEndpoint, request,
                getCallback());
```

with the webServiceTemplate being null. Also all the fields in the clientImpl are null. So the auto wiring is wrong. What way should it be done?

Comment: Are the resources part of your classpath ?

Comment: I moved my context.xml to the root of src.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by an inaccessible `client-context.xml`.

Spring was instructed to search this file on the classpath, but the directory this file was in had not been included into the classpath.

By moving the file into root (which is part of the classpath) I was able to solve the problem.

Edit:
For my second problem, I followed this guys [Designing a Java library with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471550/designing-a-java-library-with-spring)
 suggestion  and created a SpringLoader class which loaded the context and it worked.

Comment: is this a mave project